# little problem creating pkgs

Tags: make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm Trying to do something similar like the shadow hand but more easy. (Cause I do'nt need all the things that the shadow's have). in these way the importan things that i need is the next ones for now obviously:

- sr_description
- sr_hardware_interface
- sr_mechanism_model

i'm trying to do my owns : VT_hardware_interface, VT_mechanism_model,VT_description; and all are in one VirtualTouch pkg. i did pkg VT_description run make and was fine and in same way VT_hardware_interface. but when i gonna run the VT_mechanism_model that depends on one files of the VT_hardware i get the next :

```
> /home/moni/VirtualTouch/VT_mechanism_model/src/joint_0_transmission.cpp:9:49: error fatal: VT_hardware_interface/VT_actuator.hpp: No existe el archivo o el directorio
compilación terminada.
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/VT_mechanism_model.dir/src/joint_0_transmission.o] Error 1
make[3]: se sale del directorio «/home/moni/VirtualTouch/VT_mechanism_model/build»
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/VT_mechanism_model.dir/all] Error 2
make[2]: se sale del directorio «/home/moni/VirtualTouch/VT_mechanism_model/build»
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: se sale del directorio «/home/moni/VirtualTouch/VT_mechanism_model/build»
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I export the pkg ( source /opt/ros/fuerte/setup.bash AND export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=${ROS_PACKAGE_PATH}:`pwd`) on VT_hardware

and doesn't work. some idea what i'm doing wrong?
thnks

**EDIT:**

When Run :

```
> echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
```

out

```
> /opt/ros/fuerte/share:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks:/home/moni/VirtualTouch/VT_mechanism_model
```

And for rospack find VT_hardware_interface

```
[rospack] Error: stack/package VT_hardware_interface not found
```

In The same way i tried with:

```
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/moni/VirtualTouch/VT_mechanism_model:/home/moni/VirtualTouch/VT_hardware_interface
```

but it's kind the same error.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49631/little-problem-creating-pkgs/) by [monidiaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3475/monidiaz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2012-12-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-12-03**:
What do the `echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` and `rospack find VT_hardware_interface` commands print? (Please edit your question to show their output.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do not manage your package path manually but use [rosws](http://ros.org/wiki/rosws). [This page](http://ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Overlays) shows how to set up a clean workspace. Put your packages (sr_description, sr_hardware_interface and sr_mechanism_model) in the folder ~/fuerte_workspace/sandbox and, given they all provide the correct export lines in manifest.xml, compilation should just work.

**Edit** It seems like you put your dependencies right into the ros package you were creating. Don't do that. You cannot nest packages in packages, i.e. a package cannot contain another package. Instead, all three packages and your own package should be direct subdirectories of ~/fuerte_workspace/sandbox.

A few more things to check:

- Check with `echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` that you sourced the setup.bash file in ~/fuerte_workspace correctly. It should contain a path to ~/fuerte_workspace/sandbox. If it does not, re-source the setup.bash file in your terminal.
- You should be able to find your packages with rospack find, e.g.: `rospack find sr_hardware_interface`. This call should output the absolute path to the respective package. If it does not, check that the package actually contains a manifest.xml file.
- Verify that sr_hardware_interface is actually exporting C++ flags correctly: `rospack export sr_hardware_interface --lang=cpp --attrib=cflags` This command should print something like `-I/home/you/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/sr_hardware_interface/include`. If it does not, add the corresponding export lines to the manifest file.
- Verify that your package dependencies are right. For instance, the manifest file in VT_mechanism_model needs to depend on sr_hardware_interface. Make sure your dependencies are correct.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [monidiaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3475/monidiaz/) on 2012-12-04**:
I tried this, making like a new Sandbox in my pkg called VirtualTouch doing all of the page u give me, and the erros is the same . i thought that something was wrong with it so i tried copy the files on my really fuerte_workspace/sandbox that a created and utilized for the first tutorials about ros,